# the basic integral formula of harmonic function

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose that the function $u$ is a harmonic function on the outer region $\Omega^{\prime}$of bounded region $\Omega$ and satisfies
$$|u(\boldsymbol{x})| \leqslant \frac{C}{|\boldsymbol{x}|}, \quad\left|u_{x_{i}}(\boldsymbol{x})\right| \leqslant \frac{C}{|\boldsymbol{x}|^{2}}$$

, where c is a normal number. Try to derive the basic integral formula of $u$ on $\Omega^{\prime}$.

1.$\Gamma(|x|)= \begin{cases}\frac{1}{(n-2) \omega_{n}}|\boldsymbol{x}|^{2-n}, & n \geqslant 3 \\ -\frac{1}{2 \pi} \ln |\boldsymbol{x}|, & n=2\end{cases}$

$\Gamma(\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y}) \stackrel{\text { def }}{=} \Gamma(|\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y}|)$

2.If $u \in C^{1}(\bar{\Omega}) \cap C^{2}(\Omega)$ is a harmonic function in  $\Omega$ , then
$$
u(\boldsymbol{x})=\int_{\partial \Omega} \Gamma(\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y}) \frac{\partial u(\boldsymbol{y})}{\partial \boldsymbol{n}} \mathrm{d} S_{\boldsymbol{y}}-\int_{\partial \Omega} u(\boldsymbol{y}) \frac{\partial \Gamma(\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y})}{\partial \boldsymbol{n}} \mathrm{d} S_{\boldsymbol{y}}, \quad \boldsymbol{x} \in \Omega .
$$
This formula is called the basic integral formula of harmonic function.

I think it's replacing the continuous condition on the boundary with the functional control condition.But they all have the same basic formula.The proof should involve complex analysis.But I didn't think how to use this condition.Please give me a solution idea.

Comment: Please add more details and share what you have tried to do.

Comment: Are you sure you must do it via complex analysis - I don't see how it would be possible to address the case $n$ is odd.

Comment: If you want to do it via PDE methods there is a proof (after some minor adjustments) in chapter 2 of *Partial Differential Equations* by Evans.